# Exporting all records from datagridview to Excel VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I used this code to export my records to excel and it works fine, but it only exports one row. Is there anyway to record all my data in the datagridview? Also, I'm not familiar with crystal report in VB so I want to use a button click event..

```
Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next
Next

xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
xlWorkBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()

releaseObject(xlApp)
releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

MsgBox("You can find the file D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
Try
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
    obj = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    obj = Nothing
Finally
    GC.Collect()
End Try
```

I can't comment to the one who posted this code cause I have few reputation...

Comment: Bro, your question is quite unclear. What is the real problem? What does `Crystal Reports` have to do with this?

Comment: Someone said that I have to use `crystal report` to generate a report and open it with excel. But I'm not familiar with it, so I searched a few answer here and I found this code. I used this code to export `datagridview` data to excel but it only saves one row. I need to save all of the data from `datagridview` to excel. Is there any way to do that, sir?

Comment: In your code, you want to include the header also, right?

Comment: Yes, sir. I have 50 records in my `DatagridView`, but only shows one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `For Loop`.

```
   'FOR HEADERS
    For i = 1 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, i) = DataGridView1.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
        'FOR ITEMS
        For j = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 1, i) = DataGridView1(i - 1, j - 1).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: I'll try this. I'll be back in a few moments, sir :)

Comment: Ok, kindly mark this if it worked. Gonna take a break. Be back to you if that code got issues (haven't tested it).

Comment: It saves the second record but not the first one. I tried to add another record and it saves, too. Thank you so much sir :) I tested it in my sample project which has only 2 records :)

Comment: _"It saves the second record but not the first one..."_ what do you mean? Are there still problems?

Comment: In my sample project, I input two records. But only the second one will save in the excel file. I tried to input another record and it saves too. The first one didn't save in the excel file.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! You saved me for the second time. It works fine now! Again, thank you! :)

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!